# Multiple nested layout with same structure

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one relative layout and it has multiple relativelayout with exact same structure

```
<RelativeLayout

    <RelativeLayout
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each relativelayout has multiple ImageViews and TextViews.

**Problem**

How to access nested relative layouts and their children. I know, I can access them using ids but what if there are too many layouts and nested children. Giving so many unique name is quite a pain.

What is best practice to handle this?

Comment: "multiple relativelayout with exact same structure", Sounds like you should be using a `ListView`

Comment: Seriously, you probably want a ListView. It'll make your life much easier!

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. What if ListView Item itself hold such structure?

Comment: For every item of list view,  get view will be called where you can inflate any arbitrary layout based on logic

Comment: @user2095470 I don't understand, "What if ListView Item itself hold such structure?". If it did then you have such things as `onItemClick()`. [This is a pretty good ListView tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html&sa=U&ei=nGQzU_iQG8mgrAHP3oD4Cg&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNGdl3tvxihCsD2tM0aii7jn7OEr-g)